# Xamarin Binding project code generation stops unexpectedly

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin binding project that's been used for some time. I recently went to update it a little and get it hooked up to our CI server, and for some reason I find that when I build it, it seems to stop halfway through generating the code, and then try to compile it. I say this because the last few lines of `Messaging.g.cs` look like this:

```cs
[DllImport (LIBOBJC_DYLIB, EntryPoint="objc_msgSendSuper")]
public extern static bool bool_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr_UInt64_ref_IntPtr (IntPtr receiver, IntPtr selector, IntPtr arg1, global::System.UInt64 arg2, ref IntPtr arg3);
[DllImport (LIBOBJC_DYLIB, EntryPoint="objc_msgSend")]
public extern static bool bool_objc_msgSend_SByte_ref_IntPtr (IntPtr receiver, IntPtr
```

The file literally ends on that `IntPtr`, midway through a method signature. The file is 523 lines, 53248 characters, so I can't see an obvious filesize limit it's hitting, and it used to work with no problems. If I move the files across the the Mac that I'm using as a build agent and open the solution in Xamarin Studio, it builds just fine.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Update 1, with Xamarin 4.0.1.89, Xamarin.iOS 9.4.1.24.

Does anyone know what can cause this?